# Why can't I see the iOS 7.0 simulator in Xcode on Yosemite?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator, osx-yosemite

I need to do some testing on an iOS 7.0.3 Simulator, but when I go to Preferences > Downloads in Xcode (6.0.1) there is no iOS 7.0 Simulator under the Components section.

Could it be because I am running Yosemite? I've heard of Mavericks machines losing support for iOS 6.0, but couldn't find any definitive answer on whether Yosemite has removed support for 7.0 simulators.

Comment: I tried copying over old versions of the SDK from previous releases of Xcode but these aren't recognized. Anyone find a solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because you're on Yosemite. It doesn't support 7.0 anymore.
Had the same issue.

Comment: Is there documentation somewhere that confirms which versions of iOS Yosemite will support?

Answer (score 2):

XCode 6.1 in Yosemite starts with 7.1, if you need to test older iOS versions you can still install XCode 5.X from [Apple's developer downloads site](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action?name=Xcode) using your developer account. You can have both versions installed in the same machine.

Comment: You've confirmed that a Yosemite machine running Xcode 5 will allow for 7.0.1 devices?

Comment: Also, Xcode 6.0.1 does not support 7.0 devices either. It's not just Xcode 6.1.

Comment: I have Yosemite 10.10 with XCode 5.1 that comes with iOS 7.1 and  also have installed 6.1, I guess you can install every version in between. Also have XCode 6.1 that comes with iOS 8.1 and have installed 7.1. All these x.1 sound crazy in my head now.

Comment: I have older versions of xcode, but still can't get the app to even install on the simulator if I target 7.0.x or 6.x. Anyone facing the same?

Answer (score 0):

1. Open iOS Simulator is at `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Applications/iOS\ Simulator.app`.
2. Go to Hardware > Devices > Manage Devices
3. Add a simulator -> Download more simulators > Download iOS 7.1 Simulator

Comment: This question is about iOS 7.0.

Comment: This is a pretty old 'non' answer; I am not very sure what exists now.

Answer (score 0):

You can just copy simulator and framework from previous versions of Xcode. I use this method when I need to compile or test

Comment: May be release version is incompatible. I've tested about 3 months ago with simulator from 5.1 from AppStore and DP 4

Answer (score -1):

Try this iOS Simulator -> Hardware -> Device -> Manage Devices and add / remove them as required.

Comment: 7.0 doesn't appear when Yosemite is installed.