# iOS 7 Simulator not working after upgrade to MAC OS X 10.10 Yosemite

Tags: ios, xcode6, osx-yosemite

I have updated my MAC from 10.5 to 10.10 and its not able to running my ios 7.0 simulator from xcode 5
and when I am trying the same with xcode 6 and iOS 8 , its working fine , Please guide me on that I have not try to contact apple support yet so do not know what is the problem .

Comment: 'Xcode' Menu tab -> "Preferences..." -> "Downloads" : Does it have any mention about iOS 7 simulator under Components?

Comment: No its getting problem ans also I have tried with ios 7 in xcode 5

Comment: possible duplicate of [iOS 7.0 simulator not showing under downloads in Xcode 6.0.1 (Running OSX Yosemite Beta)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26364239/ios-7-0-simulator-not-showing-under-downloads-in-xcode-6-0-1-running-osx-yosemi)